# Cambio en codigo C

Tags: c

Como puede hacer que al ejecutar este código, y al poner el `scanf` me aparezca solo el 42 inicial y el número que introduje en el `scanf`. Ya que al iniciarlo como está escrito debajo aparece también un número 1

```
void funcion (void);
int global;

int main()
{
    extern int global;
    global = 42;
    funcion();
    printf( "\%d\n", global);
}

void funcion(void)
{
    extern int global;
    printf( "%d\n", global);
    global = scanf ("%d",&global);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a quitar los `extern int` de las funciones para que accedan a la variable global **int global;**, dejándolo así:

```
void funcion (void);
int global;

int main()
{
    global = 42;
    funcion();
    printf( "\%d\n", global);
}

void funcion(void)
{
    printf( "%d\n", global);
    scanf ("%d",&global);
}
```

**extern** se usa para compartir variables entre archivos de código fuente distintos

Comment: Por desgracia sigue apareciendo el uno al final. Pero gracias por la ayuda igualmente

Comment: Perdón, no me había dado cuenta de que había otro fallo, y es que estas asignando el valor de *global* al resutado de la funcion scanf (número de elementos leidos, en este caso solo lee 1). Quita esa asignación como aparece en mi respuesta editada y te debe de funcionar.